# linq query that joins results from three other queries

Tags: linq

I am trying to join results from three linq queries. The types are as follows:

`orderItems` is a `List<OrderLineItem>`

`transitTimes` is a `Dictionary<int,int>` where `Key = SiteId` and `Value = TransitDays`

`shippingPriority` is a `Dictionary<int,int>` where `Key = DefaultPriority` and `Value = SiteId`

```
public class OrderLineItem
{
    public decimal OrderLineWorkId { get; set; }
    public string Sku { get; set; }
    public string SiteId { get; set; }
    public char FlagSlapType { get; set; }
    public char FlagTruck { get; set; }
    public string SkuType { get; set; }
    public int QtyOrdered { get; set; }
    public int QtySellable { get; set; }
}

public class OrderAllocation
{
    public int SiteId { get; set; }
    public int TransitDays { get; set; }
    public int QtyItemsInStock { get; set; }
    public int QtyParcelInStock { get; set; }
    public int DefaultPriority { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my linq query, but it always returns 0 results. Not sure where I am going wrong?

```
var results =  (from i in orderItems
                join t in transitTimes on i.SiteId equals t.Key.ToString()
                join d in shippingPriority on t.Key equals d.Value
                group i by i.SiteId into g
                select new OrderAllocation()
                {
                    SiteId = Convert.ToInt32(g.Key),
                    TransitDays = transitTimes.Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault(),
                    QtyItemsInStock = g.Count(e => e.QtySellable >= e.QtyOrdered),
                    QtyParcelInStock = g.Count(e => e.QtySellable >= e.QtyOrdered && e.FlagSlapType != 'Y'),
                    DefaultPriority = defaultShippingPriority.Select(x => x.Key).FirstOrDefault()
                }).OrderBy(x => x.SiteId).ToList();
```

**UPDATE**

I found what was wrong, the `SiteId` of type `string` had a values with a prefix `0` (ie `01`, `02`, etc) and therefore would not join with values like `1`, `2`, etc. Changed type from `string` to `int` and am now getting results. Sorry for the false alarm.

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be related to differences in the data types:

```
      (from i in orderItems
        join t in transitTimes on i.SiteId equals t.Key.ToString()
```

orderItems defines SiteId as an string

```
public string SiteId { get; set; }
```

while transitTimes has a key of int

```
 Dictionary<int,int>
```

The join condition of **int** to **string** may not provide the results you are expecting.